# How is $I_{[0,\infty)}(t)$ defined?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

How is $I_{[0,\infty)}(t)$ defined? This must be a notation in probabilty theory.

Comment: It's likely an indicator function: it has value 1 on $[0,\infty)$ and 0 on $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: Although indicator functions come up in probability, it doesn't seem that an indicator over an infinite interval would come up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Heaviside Step Function $H(t)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Zero_argument):

> $H(0) = 1$ is used when $H$ needs to be right-continuous. For instance cumulative distribution functions are usually taken to be right continuous, as are functions integrated against in Lebesgue–Stieltjes integration. In this case $H$ is the indicator function of a closed semi-infinite interval:
>   $$
>     H(t) = \mathbf{I}_{[0,\infty)}(t).\, 
> $$

Comment: ...or one could use Iverson brackets as well: $[t \geq 0]$.